# Syntax error in INNER JOIN on microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

This question has likely been answered before but my search has returned no viable solutions. I am trying to append a column from a different table using inner join to allow access to both tables. This is using Microsoft Access and my code is as follows

```
SELECT Table1.* , Table2.AppendColumn
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.foo = Table2.bar);
```

I have made sure the columns are of the same data type and would appreciate a more learned opinion.

Full error is

> "Syntax error in query expression 'Table1.foo = Table2.ba'.

I do want all fields from the first table with only one column from the second table. i used the term append as it seemed accurate for what i'm doing although there is no matching or empty column in the other table. This shouldn't be any kind of special query i just created one using "Query Design" and wrote the code myself

Edit - This issue was caused by incorrect encapsulation on my end, didn't know about sql not likeing numbers at the beginning of list names, sorry for the confusion, and thanks to all who contributed.

Comment: The query looks "MS-Access"-correct to me.

Comment: and what would be the error message?

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: `foo` and `bar` are the same data type?  You want a `Select` query showing all fields from `Table1` and just `AppendColumn` from `Table2`, or do you mean you have an empty field in `Table1` and you want to append the values from `AppendColumn` into the empty field - an `append` query?

Comment: Full error is "Syntax error in query expression 'Table1.foo = Table2.ba'
@MarkRotteveel yes the columns are the same data type, and i do want all fields from the first table with only one column from the second table. i used the term append as it seemed accurate for what i'm doing although there is no matching or empty column in the other table.

This shouldn't be any kind of special query i just created one using "Query Design" and wrote the code myself.

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information in the question.

Comment: So just to be sure: the column `AppendColumn` _exists_ in `Table2`, and the column you want to join on is named `bar` or `ba` as you posted in the error message?

Comment: Correct the column exists in the table specified. and microsoft access is clipping the last letter of the column in the error message so it is 'bar' but shows up as ba.

Comment: what if you remove the parentheses?

Comment: the error persists regardless of parentheses

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your two Table Design views? And what do you mean by `i just created one using "Query Design" and wrote the code myself` ?

Comment: As was said, your problem got lost in translation from your original SQL to `Table1.foo = Table2.bar`. To help you, we need to see the *actual* original SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only likely issues you can be encountering here is if something is incorrectly referenced in your actual code. Or if there is a major flaw in the SQL structure itself (such as hidden characters messing things up).

Highly suggest checking the name of each table and both of the inner join column names for any possible reference errors.

This could be something finicky like "Table1.Foo Bar" but would need to be "Table1.[Foo Bar]" as Access does not accept spaces in references. Same would apply to any column starting with a number or a symbol.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Table1.* , Table2.[Append Column]
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.[foo bar] = Table2.[1050])
```

But as it stands now, your code is correct as listed.